# Saving a timer string to shared prefs

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, sharedpreferences

I am currently making a timer app that starts on tap and stops and lists the time on another tap in a sliding up panel. I have a class that gets the string of the timer which looks like this

```
class Dependencies {
  final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  CurrentTime currentTime;
  List<String> savedTime = List<String>();

  transformTimeToString(int milliseconds) {
    currentTime = transformTimeToTime(stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);

    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

    String hundredsStr = (hundreds % 100).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString();
    String secondsMinStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString();
    if (currentTime.minutes > 0) {
      return '$minutesStr:$secondsMinStr.$hundredsStr';
    } else {
      return '$secondsStr.$hundredsStr';
    }
  }

  transformTimeToTime(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

    return CurrentTime(
      hundreds: hundreds % 100,
      seconds: seconds % 60,
      minutes: minutes % 60,
    );
  }
}
```

So I am having trouble listing that string on a json file to then save it to shared preferences. It would very helpful if someone with a great understanding could push me in the right direction with the code. Thanks Hunter

Here's Links to everything [Timer Page](https://github.com/HunterColly/Speed-Cuber/blob/566eae5a2f2742ebe94a4fa0ffc34411575b4e3a/lib/Screens/Timer.dart),[Timer String](https://github.com/HunterColly/Speed-Cuber/blob/566eae5a2f2742ebe94a4fa0ffc34411575b4e3a/lib/classes/dependencies.dart), [Whole project](https://github.com/HunterColly/Speed-Cuber/tree/566eae5a2f2742ebe94a4fa0ffc34411575b4e3a)

Comment: Add the code of what you've tried for saving the saving the string to `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is a bit unclear, so I am assuming you want to save the `List<String> savedTime;` into SharePreference and reload it again somehow.

```
saveTimeList(String key, List<String> savedTime) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setStringList(key, savedTime);
}
```

Retrieve like this:

```
Future<Set<String>> loadSavedTime(String key) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> stringValue = prefs.getStringList(key) ?? [];
  #Input your additional code to convert String back to Time if you want
  #
  return stringValue.toSet();
}
```

Comment: anywhere you like